# The pentagon in isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry

The triangle with the sides a,a,and b is isoscele.cut off from  it two triangle, symmetric to each other with respect to the altitude perpendicular to the base b,so that the remaining symmetric pentagon is equilateral. Express the sides x of pentagon in terms of a and b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A triangle that you cut off has sides $a-x$,  ${1\over2}(b-x)$, and $x$. Apply the cosine theorem to this triangle, knowing that $\cos\alpha={b\over 2a}$. In this way you obtain a quadratic equation for $x$. For good measure you should check what are allowable values for $b$, given $a$.